# Google Analytics: cross domain tracking without URL parameters

Tags: google-analytics

Just had a quick question: right now when you are doing cross domain tracking with Analytics, the URL has parameters added to them to track it. I was just wondering, is there a way to use something like POST or any other method to pass the cookie info from one domain to the next so the URL does not seem so messy with all the URL parameters being added.

E.g. going from google.com to yahoo.com/lots_of_paramters, could we go to just yahoo.com/gclid=123

Cheers,
Yuri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters are read on the other domain to recreate the same Google Analytics cookies.

Data sent on POST is not available on the posted page through Javascript only on the back end. So you would need the backend to actually store this data and send back to the interface, maybe through AJAX to recreate the cookies there.

Another idea is probably to try to parse the cookies server side and send them as new cookies, so the Javascript code on the destination domain wouldn't need to recreate the cookies, they would be normal HTTP Header set cookies.

Still it's a lot of work and fuzz just to pass the cookies on. Urls are ugly but are still the easiest and portable way to handle the problem.

Comment: is it actually save to just copy the cookies on the server side? are they in fact identical?